# Cant change value of boolean read column in rails for notification system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, notifications

I am implementing a notification system for my app. I created a table notifications that belongs to model User ( a User has many notifications ). Table notification has columns content(string) and read(boolean)
Ive got a navbar with a dropdown that displays the unread notifications and a script which is suppose to change the read column of a notification from false to true through an ajax post on click.

```
<script>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdownMenu1").on('click', function(event){
      $.ajax({url: "<%=update_notification_path%>",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          success: function() {
                          $(".noti_bubble").hide();

                        },
      });
    });
 });
```

this ajax leads to an action of my notifications_controller that looks like this:

```
def update_notif
    current_user.notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.read == true
      notification.save
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

But after that when I check in the rails console the read boolean nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: can you describe where `update_notification_path` is defined?

Comment: in config/routes
`post "updatenotif", to: "notifications#update", as: "update_notification"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update method like this `notification.read == true` to `notification.read = true`.

```
def update_notif
   current_user.notifications.each do |notification|
     notification.read = true
     notification.save
   end
   render nothing: true
end
```

Comment: I found the mistake: 
my route was 
to: "notifications#update"
whereas my controller action was update_notif !

Comment: ==  Checks if the value of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true

Comment: =  Simple assignment operator, Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand